# Do the cosets of in invariant (normal) subgroup consist entirely of classes?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H$ be an invariant subgroup of some group $G$. Is it then true that the cosets of $H$ consist entirely of conjugacy classes?

The question was prompted by something I was thinking about in representation theory. As above, suppose $H$ is an invariant subgroup. Then we can consider the quotient group $F=G/H$. We note that $f: G \to F$ defined by $f(g)=gH$ is a homomorphism.

Now suppose $T$ is a representation of $F$. Then the composition $T \circ f$ is a representation of $G$. Under this representation, the character of some $g \in G$ is simply the character of $T(gH)$, so all elements in a coset $gH$ have the same character. We also know that elements in the same conjugacy class always have the same character. Hence we might suspect that a conjugacy class $C$ is contained entirely in a single coset. Does this have to be the case?

Comment: For a counterexample consider the case when $H$ is trivial. Then the cosets are just the elements of $G$. I think what you conjecture is true if and only if $G/H$ is abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks!

Comment: "Invariant subgroup" was used in the past, but it's now quite old-fashioned and especially inconvenient (one might be invariant under another group action). The common widely used terminology is "normal subgroup".

Comment: @DerekHolt maybe you mean that you expect that the conjecture is true for given $G$ and all subgroups $H$, only when $G$ is abelian. By the way, I'm not sure of the meaning of the conjecture. If it means that every coset of $H$ is a single conjugacy class, then this is only true when $G$ is abelian and $H=1$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the tip! No, I do not mean that every coset H is a single conjugacy class. I mean that all ements in H belongs to a conjugacy class which is contained wholly in H. Put differently: conjugate elements cannot belong to different cosets.

Comment: Then this is true if and only if $G/H$ is abelian (as Derek said! he better guessed what you mean than me)

Comment: @YCor Ok, thanks!